# How to replace "@" post tag with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
aaaaa @username bbbb cc ddddddd
```

İ want get this tag and replace or preg_replace to html.

like this,

```
aaaaa <a href="/username/">@username</a> bbbb cc ddddddd
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice see that if you haven't already.

Comment: i have this but i didnt find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `preg_replace` with the pattern `/@([^ ]*)/`, which will allow you to capture the keyword `username` to be used in the replacement you want.

```
$input = "aaaaa @username bbbb cc ddddddd";
$output = preg_replace("/@([^ ]*)/", "<a href=\"/$1/\">@$1</a>", $input);
echo $output;
```

**Output:**

```
aaaaa <a href="/username/">@username</a> bbbb cc ddddddd
```

## Demo